# "used to always say that" or "used to always to say that"

Tags: infinitives, adverb-placement, conjugations

Background: [Here is a link to an English tutorial video](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTYzNyZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTYzNyZlZD0yMDE0LTEwLTE3VDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4). In it, the speaker says:

> You know, my father **used to always to say that** 'a good leader is born, not made'.

But in [this hotel review](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187337-d202274-r8066827-Sheraton_Frankfurt_Airport_Hotel_Conference_Center-Frankfurt_Hesse.html), I see:

> They **used to always say that** their pool was being repaired, but 5 years later they have finally taken it off their list of ammenities.

So, which one is correct?

**"used to always *to* say that"** or **"used to always say that"**?

Comment: @Stephie - If I had known you were editing, I wouldn't have been doing the same thing :^) I am able to access the video, so I left the link in.

Comment: In the video, though, the speaker says, "You know, my father used to always say..." There is no second _to_.

Comment: in the text of that video you can choose the sentence by clicking on it. then you can hear only the chosen sentence. and it is clear that the speaker says "always to say".

Comment: I think there are 3 grammatical ways to say it:  "He always used to say that." "He used to always say that" and "He used always to say that" (probably much rarer nowadays than the first two.) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+used+to+say%2C+used+always+to+say%2C+used+to+always+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20used%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20always%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20to%20always%20say%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**used to always say that** is the more correct of the two; the other is definitely incorrect.  The confusion probably arises because of the "always" splitting the auxiliary verb "used to" from the main verb "say".  **always used to say that** would probably be more correct, and in my opinion at least, more clear.

Comment: unfortunately it is not the first time that I find typing mistake in the text of that tutorial videos.

Comment: Well, if it's a free site, you're getting your money's worth!